# Webdriver. How to retrieve the xpath of found element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, children

I have a bit of code that finds an element based on visible text.

```
# Defines the text I am looking for
productName = "customer x job"
#Finds the element I am looking for
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='demo_top']/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a".format(productName))
```

I need to click a box just to the right of this.

The specific xpath of the element is:

```
#What I just found
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a
#The box I actually want to click
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/span/a
```

So I just need to add "/span/a" to the xpath of inputElement. The issue is, I don't know the specific xpath of this element. Is there a way for me to convert inputElement to a specific xpath, so I can just append "/span/a" to the end of it and click that element?

Edit: seems I was mistaken, I need to replace the final "a" with "span/a"

Below is the html:

```
<li class="TCbullet">
<span>
<a class="editCategory " onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe' } );" href="cat-frame-category.php?categoryID=1340"> </a>  #I want to click this
<span class="sort">sort: 0</span>
</span>
<a class="anchorCategory" alt="Eden Cognitive Content" href="?ownerID=C518&g=1085&t=1340">Eden Cognitive Content</a>  # I have found this
</li>
```

I want to access the editCatagory link, and I have found the anchorCategory link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_xpath) on the element you have already found:

```
link = inputElement.find_element_by_xpath('./preceding-sibling::span/a')
```

This would select the `a` tag inside the `span` that is following the `a` tag you have found.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I could do that. It seems I was incorrect about something though, and you may be able to help. It looks like I missed that there is an a tag at the end of the first xpath. Is there a way to replace that last 'a' with 'span/a' ?

Comment: @user3784334 could you please show the relevant html, so I can be sure about the html structure? Thanks. Just edit the question and paste it there.

Comment: @user3784334 ok, it appears that the `span/a` is before the `a` you have found, edited the answer - try with `preceding-sibling`, should work. Thanks.